# Insert column delimiters before pattern in a sorted file on a mac

Tags: macos, unix, multiple-columns

Have a resulting file which contains values from different XML files.

The file have 5 columns separated by ";" in case that all pattern matched.

First column = neutral Index

Second column = specific Index1

Third column = file does contain Index1

Fourth column = specific Index2

Fifth column = file does contain Index2

Not matching pattern with Index2 (like last three lines) should also have 5 columns, while the last two columns should be like the first two lines.

The sorted files looks like:

```
AAA;AAA.1D1;file_X;AAA.2D1;file_Y
AAA;AAA.1E1;file_A;AAA.2E1;file_B
AAA;AAA.2F1;file_C
BBB;BBB.2G1;file_D
CCC;CCC.1B1;file_H
YYY;YYY.2M1;file_N
```

The desired result would be:

```
AAA;AAA.1D1;file_X;AAA.2D1;file_Y
AAA;AAA.1E1;file_A;AAA.2E1;file_B
AAA;;;AAA.2F1;file_C
BBB;;;BBB.2G1;file_D
CCC;CCC.1B1;file_H;;
YYY;;;YYY.2M1;file_N
```

If you have any idea/hint, your help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

In the light of the updated requirement, I think you want something like this:

```
awk -F';' 'NF==3 && $2~/\.1/{$0=$0 ";;"}
           NF==3 && $2~/\.2/{$0=$1 ";;;" $2 ";" $3} 1' file
```

which can be written as a one-liner:

```
awk -F';' 'NF==3 && $2~/\.1/{$0=$0 ";;"} NF==3 && $2~/\.2/{$0=$1 ";;;" $2 ";" $3} 1' YourFile
```

**Original Answer**

I would do that with `awk`:

```
awk -F';' 'NF==3{$0=$1 ";;;" $2 ";" $3}1' YourFile

AAA;AAA.1D1;file_X;AAA.2D1;file_Y
AAA;AAA.1E1;file_A;AAA.2E1;file_B
AAA;;;AAA.2F1;file_C
BBB;;;BBB.2G1;file_D
YYY;;;YYY.2M1;file_N
```

That says...*"run `awk` on `YourFile` using `';'` as field separator. If there are only 3 fields on any line, recreate the line using the existing first field, three semi-colons and then the other two fields. The `1` at the end, means print the current line`"*.

If you don't use `awk` much, `NF` refers to the number of fields, `$0` refers to the entire current line, `$1` refers to the first field on the line, `$2` refers to the second field etc.

Comment: Thanks! It works. I did always tried to get the matching line by searching the pattern *.2* and used also awk, but always fail. Thanks a lot. Short and efficient! Thanks for detailed explanation!

Comment: Just tested with all files and think I have to adjust it in respect of the pattern <code> *.1* </code> and <code> *.2* </code> because facing now the aspect that I have also entries like <code> CCC;CCC.1B1;file_H </code> which should be turned into <code> CCC;CCC.1B1;file_H;; </code>.

Comment: It's really hard to read formatted data in the *comments* section. Please click `edit` under your original question and update the input data and result data to reflect the files better then I will try and update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, first time I write in chat ... Can’t delete the last comment anymore. My former comment was: Just tested with all files and think I have to adjust it in respect of the pattern `.1` and `.2` because facing now the aspect that I have also entries like `CCC;CCC.1B1;file_H` which should be turned into `CCC;CCC.1B1;file_H;;`

Comment: Just edit the question and expand it with the example of `CCC;CCC.1B1;file_H`. I didn't forecast this possible result in my initial question. In summary, all entries `*.1*` are in the second column with the associated file in the third and all entries `*.2*` are in the fourth with the associated file in the fifth column. Hope I express myself understandable.

Comment: **Brilliant!** Works like a charm! Checked all results and everything is fine. Thank you very much!